# Django Upgrade : relation "django_content type" does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes, generic-foreign-key

I upgraded my django version from 1.7.5 to 1.9.2. All migration ran but when i run tests i get below error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
```

I checked the database and the django_content_type model exists. I am using PostgreSQL.

I am only getting this error on PostgreSQL not in Sqlite3..

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py", line 129, in 
    utility.execute()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py", line 104, in execute
    PycharmTestCommand().run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py", line 91, in handle
    failures = TestRunner(test_labels, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, failfast=failfast, keepdb='--keepdb' in sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_runner.py", line 256, in run_tests
    extra_tests=extra_tests, **options)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_test_runner.py", line 156, in run_tests
    return super(DjangoTeamcityTestRunner, self).run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 532, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 482, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 726, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 70, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 119, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 172, in handle
    self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 293, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/Mac/my_env_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
```

Comment: Could you be running the tests on a unmigrated test database?

Comment: @HåkenLid No...i created new database and migrated...and then i ran test cases

Comment: Seems to be related to the pycharm test runner. It sure looks as though the test database has not been migrated. Have you tried running tests without `--keepdb`?

Comment: @HåkenLid i ran test on terminal as well...but nooo success...same issue..

Comment: @HåkenLid i m getting error only on postgres SQL  not on SQLite3

Comment: What does `django-admin showmigrations --plan` give you?
`contenttypes.0001_initial` should be first. You might have to manually edit some of your own migration files to add migrations from contenttypes app as dependency, or even rebuild all your migration files.

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error. I upgraded django from 1.4.21 to 1.8.9, all migrations ran, but can not run test. Each time I ran test, I deleted the test database and created a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used uuid field and JSON field in old Django version but in new version these fields are default provided by django models. So i replaced these fields with django default fields and created migrations again....

Now Its working without any issue..